# gVim gives [Permission Denied] when using --remote-silent

Tags: windows, batch-file, vim

I'm editing Unity 3D .cs files in gVim on Windows 7, I'd like when I double click a file in Unity for the file to open in an existing vim window, but instead it opens a new one.

To get around this I used various other SO answers to make a batch file and call vim using --remote-silent. This all works apart from vim acts like it wont allow remote commands to run on it.

Batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Continue
   start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe" --remote-silent ":sp %1<CR>"
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Continue
```

It gives me

```
":sp C:\my\path\file.cs" [Permission Denied] Press enter or type command to continue
```

I tried removing the "%1" to check if it was the file that was giving the permission error, but no luck. The batch file runs via a shortcut that runs as administrator (nothing is ever simple in Windows)

Unity -> Shortcut -> Batch file -> gVim -> ":sp filename"

Any ideas why vim won't let this command run?

Can't seem to find any mention of permissions in vim help -remote files or anyone else seeing this on google.

Thanks.

**Edit 1*
Looks like something weird si going on, if I do :ls I see this in my buffer list

```
2 %a=  ":sp C:\My\file\path.cs" line 1
```

Like its treating the whole command as the file path or something?

Comment: and what is `<cr>`? If you have it in real there you should remove it.

Comment: it should just run it like pressing enter.

Comment: gvim.exe -p --remote-tab-silent %1 %*

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936501/let-gvim-always-run-a-single-instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--remote-silent` takes a *file list*, not Ex commands (well, you can pass one via `+{cmd}` before the files); that's why Vim interprets your command as a (non-existing) file.

Using `--remote-send` is the correct approach; like in the help examples, you should prepend `<C-\><C-N>` to ensure that the remote Vim is in *normal mode* (otherwise, if you've left it in insert mode, the commands would be inserted literally!)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself after spotting the buffer issue.

I changed my batch to the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Continue
   start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe" --remote-send ":sp %1<CR>"
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Continue
```

Looks like --remote-silent doesn't do what I thought it did.

I also added `set shortmess=aoOtI` to my vimrc to stop it prompting me.