# GVim: Open in a new tab

Tags: windows, vim

I am using gVim on Windows and facing the annoying thing of having a new gVim window opened whenever I open a new file. Is it possible to make it open a new tab in the same window?

Thanks,
Rafid

Comment: The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894811/open-files-in-existing-gvim-in-multiple-new-tabs/894857#894857 You just need to put some wrapper scripts/desktop icons around the solution. Another solution is documented here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Launch_files_in_new_tabs_under_Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open files in existing Gvim in multiple (new) tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894811/open-files-in-existing-gvim-in-multiple-new-tabs)

Answer (score 3):

Also (more tedious but generally useful for other things) you can drag&drop files from Windows Explorer into gVim when the command line is active.  If you type `:e` and then drop a file, the command line will be filled out with the full path to the file.  You can do the same with `:sp` and `:tabe`; just remember to put the space after the command!