# How to open new file in previous gvim window

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

When I open a file in gvim from terminal using `gvim abc.cpp`, unlike **gedit** it is opening in new **gvim** window. Can anyone suggest some way to open new file in a new tab in previously opened **gvim** window? I couldn't find any information regarding this on searching. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Vim version is 7.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open files in existing Gvim in multiple (new) tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894811/open-files-in-existing-gvim-in-multiple-new-tabs)

Comment: Stack Overflow immediately finds multiple duplicates and shows then in the _Related_ column on the right: also [GVim: Open in a new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574446/gvim-open-in-a-new-tab?rq=1)

Comment: Oh sorry, the word 'existing' didn't click to me while searching. I was repeatedly using 'previous' for finding answer. Thank you.

Comment: `:h remote`   `:h --servername`

Comment: +1 @IngoKarkat, I didn't notice the column. I just gave it a try by pressing "Ask Question" and filled the OP's question, some related useful(read duplicated) topics were listed as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
gvim --remote-silent abc.cpp
```

The -silent prevents an error message from showing if there is not already a instance of GVim running