# gVim: How to load multiple files in buffer?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Im in windows and is new in using gvim. I am using the Nerdtree plugin for project navigations. Right now I open files from the nerd tree, vim will then load this opened files in the buffer. I find it easier to switch throug multiple files using the :b command, it gets more convenient after opening more files as more is loaded in the buffer.

But I think it will be more convenient if there is a way to load all files in a directory in the buffer at the same time instead of loading one by one when opening them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can specify multiple files on the command line (or right-click 'Open with Single Vim' in windows).

Equivalently, you can add or change the argument list after starting:

```
:args *.cs
```

<sup>Replaces the argument list, opening all files as buffers, showing just one</sup>

```
:argadd **/.java
```

<sup>Appends all java files in the tree below the current directory to the argument lst, opening them as buffers, keeping the active buffer in the current window unchanged</sup>

There are several other nice commands in relation to this:

```
:argdo %s/version_1-6-0/version_1-6-1/g
:bufdo g/SECRET/d
```

<sup>(apply commands to all files in argument list vs. all open buffers)</sup>

```
:sall
:tab sall
```

<sup>(open all loaded buffers in separate windows, optionally in tabs)</sup>

---

#### OT hint: to clear out the buffer list

```
:bufdo bclose
:bufdo bwipeout
:bufdo bwipeout!
```

#### Set the current directory:

```
:cd $HOME/myproject/subdir
```

Set it to the dir of the currently open file:

```
:cd %:h
```

This is very handy with tools like `:argadd *.cpp` or `:!ctags -R .` etc.

Comment: I've got an autocmd, `autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h:gs/ /\\ /`, which switches the current directory whenever I switch buffers.  Very handy for the reasons listed here.

Comment: In the `:argadd` example it should be `:argadd **/*.java` instead of `:argadd **/.java`

Answer (score 2):

```
vim mydir/*
```

Should do the trick

Edit:

Oops, windows.  I just found this similar thread quickly, which might be of some help.

[Open files in existing Gvim in multiple (new) tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894811/open-files-in-existing-gvim-in-multiple-new-tabs)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the **[project plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69&rating=life_changing)** for Vim, you could open all files under the currently selected entry.

Note that an entry is not only limited to be a folder, you could e.g. place all your needed includes in one entry and then open them in one go.

The plugin gives you also more project-relevant features like grepping through all files of the currently selected entry and many more.

Setting up your project is a little effort, but once you've done that, it's really comfortable.

Comment: Thx. That sounds interesting (although I have a tendency to prefer vanilla Vim)